# Is there a way to map a sqlalchemy column with `os.path.realpath` in an ORM query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a sqlite database with sqlalchemy that stores information about specific files on my filesystem. Something like this:

```
class FilePath(BaseModel):
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

   filepath = Column(String, nullable=False)
   whatever = Column(String)
```

I store absolute paths in the `filepath` column, however not always the *real path* (i.e. there might be some symlinks somewhere in it. For example:

```
$ tree
.
└── mydata
    ├── linkdir -> realdir/
    └── realdir
        └── file.txt
```

The database could contain either the filepath string `"mydata/realdir/file.txt"`, or `"mydata/linkdir/file.txt"` - no way to know which.

Is there a way to map the `filepath` column contents to their *real paths* at the time of the query?

```
# I have a path, I want to see if it's in the db
real_path = "mydata/realdir/file.txt"

# Run a query
fetched = session.query(FilePath).filter(FilePath.filepath == real_path)

# If no path was found, I can't say whether it's because the file isn't in db, or
# if it's present but recorded under a different logical path "mydata/linkdir/file.txt"
```

Is it possible to query this model, using the *real paths* as they exist at the time of the query?

Comment: One approach would be to write a custom `realpath` SQLite function in C, create a view in the SQLite database that calls the function on the existing path value, and then query the view. It probably won't provide great performance, however.

Comment: Yeah, have to accept that the performance of this will be bad since it'd have to resolve the paths on the filesystem for every single record in the database, every time.. I can live with that though, I'll take a look at what's involved with writing a custom SQLite C function. Is there any hope of handing much/any of that in the sqlalchemy/ORM layer?

Comment: Python's sqlite3 API has a [create_function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.create_function) method that may at least let you avoid messing around with C code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [create_function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.create_function) method in Python's sqlite3 module to create a custom `realpath` function in SQLite and then use it with `func` in a query:

```py
import os

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, String, func
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")


def _realpath(virtpath):
    return os.path.realpath(virtpath)


cnxn = engine.raw_connection()
cnxn.create_function("realpath", 1, _realpath)

Base = declarative_base()


class FileLocation(Base):
    __tablename__ = "file_location"

    path = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    comment = Column(String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<FileLocation(path='{self.path}')>"


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

thing = FileLocation(
    path="/usr/bin/python3", comment="symlink to /usr/bin/python3.6"
)
session.add(thing)
session.commit()

result = (
    session.query(FileLocation)
    .filter(func.realpath(FileLocation.path) == "/usr/bin/python3.6")
    .first()
)
print(result)
"""console output:
<FileLocation(path='/usr/bin/python3')>
"""
```